# Emacs and ESS: Using the correct version of R

Tags: r, emacs23, ess

I have installed R-2.9.1 and I am using Emacs+ESS. When I start an R process, though, the version of R that gets used by Emacs is 2.6.  I thought maybe Emacs was running R from a weird starting directory.  However, if I select my home directory ESS still starts R 2.6. (Running R at the terminal correctly brings up version 2.9.1.)

How do I add a new ESS process, or change the properties of the current R process, so that I can run my newer version of R?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding something like the following to your ~/.emacs file:

```
(setq inferior-R-program-name "c:/path/to/Rterm.exe")
```

and restart emacs.